# What are the possible reasons for registers to be offset by 1 in GDB?

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb, gnu, cortex-m

The microcontroller is an **STM32 F767ZI**, which contains a **32 bit ARM Cortex M7**

When setting values to the registers, the registers all appear to be offset by 1.

For example, the following code:

core.S

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m7
.fpu softvfp
.thumb

// Global memory locations
.global vtable
.global reset_handler

 .type vtable, %object
 vtable:
    .word _estack
    .word reset_handler
.size vtable, .-vtable

/*
 * The Reset handler
 */
 .type reset_handler, %function
 reset_handler:
    // The '_estack' value is defined in the linker script
    LDR sp, =_estack
    

    // Dummy values
    LDR r5, =0xDEADBEEF
    MOV r3, #50
    
.size reset_handler, .-reset_handler
```

linkerScripts/stm32-767zi.ld

```
_estack = 0x20080000;

MEMORY
{
    FLASH ( rx )        : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 2048K
    RAM ( rxw )         : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 512K
}
```

When compiled by running:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp -c -O0 -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -Wall core.S -o core.o`

And then...

`arm-none-eabi-gcc core.o -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -Wall --specs=nosys.specs -nostdlib -lgcc -T./linkerScripts/stm32-767zi.ld -o main.elf`

Results in:

[image: register values]

As you can see, `r6` is set to `0xdeadbeef` rather than `r5`, which is what was written in the code earlier. This offset is the same with the other two registers that were set.

I believe the values for the linker script are correct, so I would assume the issue is a result of an incorrect configuration elsewhere.

So, I am a little unsure of how to proceed from here, and ask if anyone has any ideas or suggestions as to what could be the issue.

Comment: This is quite curious!  I've never seen something like this before.  Perhaps a bug in the JTAG implementation?

Comment: Could you provide some information on the JTAG probe, GDB server software, GDB version  you are using ?

Comment: This isn't related to the question at all, but it looks like you are trying to make a very minimal implementation.  To that goal, you could drop the load to sp, since the hardware already does that for you from the first entry in the vector.

Comment: please provide a compilete example that includes the code not running into the ether and where you stopped the program to examine the registers

Comment: why are you using gcc instead of gas and ld?

Comment: @Frant the board has an ST-LINK/V2 debugger, and I am using the [ST-LINK drivers](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html) as well as [stlink](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink) as the GDB server software. I am using the latest version of the GDB software (v1.6.1)

Comment: @old_timer I have just tried compiling it with `arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -g -c core.S -o core.o` then `arm-none-eabi-ld core.o -T linkerScripts/stm32-767zi.ld -o main.elf`, but still get the same result

Comment: @old_timer I also added an infinite loop at the end of the program, and stopped it there. Previously, I simply let it run to the end and then checked the register values.

Comment: @fuz how could I go about looking into this further? The board has a built-in ST-LINK/V2 debugger/JTAG.

Comment: @user15278978 I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried including an instruction like `stm` (store multiple) to write a bunch of register values to memory, where you can look at them with GDB?  And just checking the machine code to make sure it's encoding the right register in the load instruction?  A GDB bug would be my first guess, like a mismatch between some struct layout definition vs. what's actually there.

Comment: @user15278978 You could convert your on-board stlink-v2 into a segger J-Link using one of the [ST-LINK on-board firmwares](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/) The operation is reversible, and this would remove all ST software from the picture - disclaimer: do it at your own risk - I did it on my Nucleo Cortex-M33 board. A more conservative approach would be to try debugging your program using  openocd with your stlink-v2. The goal would be the same, i.e. identifying which piece of software is the culprit. What is the version of your GDB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, having seen the majority of comments suggesting that it is likely an issue with the GDB server, I decided to give another GDB server a go.

The outcome was very pleasing:

[image: correct registers]

For:

core.S

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m7
.fpu softvfp
.thumb

// Global memory locations
.global vtable
.global reset_handler

 .type vtable, %object
 vtable:
    .word _estack
    .word reset_handler
.size vtable, .-vtable

/*
 * The Reset handler
 */
 .type reset_handler, %function
 reset_handler:
    // The '_estack' value is defined in the linker script
    LDR sp, =_estack
    

    // Dummy values
    LDR r5, =0xDEADBEEF
    MOV r3, #50
    
.size reset_handler, .-reset_handler
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Oringinally, I was using [stlink v1.6.1](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/releases/tag/v1.6.1) on Windows, however I switched over to the GDB which comes as [part of the STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00613038-stm32cubeide-stlink-gdb-server-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

It appears that the issue was indeed with the GDB server.

Thank you to everyone for the help and suggestions, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I was under the impression that the GDB interface which is accessed by entering `arm-none-eabi-gdb` was the client, and the software which handles the USB connection to the external device and the 'client' connects to, is called the server? Apologies if this is not the case... I am fairly new to all this. Is this correct or am I straight up wrong? Please correct me if so!

Comment: That is the case, `arm-none-eabi-gdb` is the client.  You talked about using something "on Windows", and changing to something else, so I assumed you were talking about changing clients.  But apparently with JTAG, the GDB server also runs on your desktop and handles a USB connection.  Thanks for clarifying, I'd only used GDB remote-debugging with stuff like qemu where an emulator is the GDB server.  I wasn't sure there even would be a "server" with a JTAG setup.